# Is it possible to save GBTClassifier in Spark 1.6?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, save, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have trained a GBTClassifier in Spark 1.6 with the Pipeline abstraction and I am kind of confused on how to save it.

If I do:

```
GBTClassificationModel gbt = trainClassifierGBT(data);
Model Accuracy = 0.8306451612903226
Test Error = 0.16935483870967738
GradientBoostedTreesModel oldGBT = gbt.toOld();
oldGBT.save(jsc.sc(), "data/gbtModel");
```

I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If I do:

```
PipelineModel pipeModel = pipeline.fit(training);
pipeline.save("data/gbtModel");
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Pipeline write will fail on this Pipeline because it contains a stage which does not implement Writable.
```

I will test this solution but wonder if it can be solved another way.
[Spark ML Pipeline api save not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732890/spark-ml-pipeline-api-save-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

As for now (Spark 1.6.0 / 2.0.0 SNAPSHOT) it is not possible because `GBTClassificationModel` is not `MLWritable` and `toOld` method you try to use is private in `ML`

If you want to save your models you'll have to use `MLlib` model directly which is `savable`:

```
final GradientBoostedTreesModel model = ...;
model.save(jsc.sc(), "some-path");
```

Comment: Thanks. But honestly what good is it for it you can't save you trained models? No pun against you but this is really crazy.

Comment: Well, to be fair this is still an `@experimental` feature.

Comment: You can still serialize the pipeline / model even though the model is not Writable, it requires a little more work though.

Comment: @UlysseMizrahi Not in a general case. You want be able to do it with distributed models.